# issue with a 4xx client error

Tags: error-handling

I'm getting a 4XX client error, I have never come across these before (maybe naively).

This is frustrating me, because my page seems to be working fine but when scanning it for SEO purposes I am getting two 4xx client error in

Put simply, what are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [HTTP 1.1 RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) explains and lists all of the 4xx errors.

"The 4xx class of status code is intended for cases in which the client seems to have erred."